# next(error) has HTML in the body response when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, vite

I'm writing a middleware function that handles 404 status codes when an endpoint is not valid.

When using Postman, the body response is:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qaPl.png)

I would like for the response to just be the error message; and not HTML. I am using Vite, as well as a Vite wrapper for Express. Repo for the moduleis here: (https://github.com/szymmis/vite-express).

**Controller Logic for one of the routes:**

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";

//MongoDB Schema Import
import { Project } from "../models/projectsMod";

const allProjects = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const findProjects = await Project.find();
  try {
    res.json({ message: "Success.", count: findProjects.length, projects: findProjects });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
};

export { allProjects }
```

**Middleware Logic:**

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";


const notFoundHandler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   const error = new Error(`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} not found.`)
   error['status'] = 404
   next(error)
};

export { notFoundHandler };
```

**Server Logic:**

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import express from "express";
import ViteExpress from "vite-express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

//MongoDB Config Import
import { databaseConnection } from "./db/config";

//Route Import
import routes from "./routes/index";

//Middleware Import
import logger from "./middleware/logging";
import { notFoundHandler } from "./middleware/errorHandler";

//Application Instance
const app = express();

//Database Connection
databaseConnection();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger);
app.use(routes);
app.use(notFoundHandler)

//typecast process.env as number; default type is string | undefined
const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);

mongoose.connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log(`MongoDB Connection: ${mongoose.connection.host}`);
  ViteExpress.listen(app, PORT, () =>
    console.log(`Server is running on: ${PORT}`)
  );
});
```

Would appreciate any advice! It's not a huge deal, and the logic is working properly... just it is weird that it's not throwing ONLY the error, but the entire HTML body.

Thank you!

**EDIT** Thank you for the suggestions! I realized I was not passing the next(error) to another middleware that sets the response to how I would like it.

Here is my updated code:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";


const notFoundHandler = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   const error = new Error(`${req.method} ${req.originalUrl} not found.`)
   error['status'] = 404
   next(error)
};

const globalErrorHandler = (error: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   res.status(error['status'] || 500)
   res.json({ error: error.message })
}

export { notFoundHandler, globalErrorHandler };
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show an example of the response you'd like to receive?

Comment: Why is your `notFoundHandler()` function calling `next(err)`.  It should just send whatever error response you want to send.  You are abdicating the sending of a response to the default handler rather than just taking charge of what happens.

Answer (score 0):

See [Writing error handlers](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers).

The default error handler produces the HTML page you're seeing. If you want to customise it, add in some error handling middleware after other middleware, routes, etc

```js
// ...
app.use(notFoundHandler);
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // see https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err);
  }

  res.status(err.status ?? err.statusCode ?? 500).send(err.message);
});
```